# pdf download functionality asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a web site in asp.net with c sharp.
I need to place a download file functionality(pdf, doc, xls) on one of my web page.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? You can make your code send any file you'd like to the client.

Comment: You should have a look at HttpHandler to achieve that. Check this [example](http://dodgethecode.blogspot.com/2008/09/large-file-download-using-httphandler.html).

Comment: Read MSDN article - Upload and Download file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this automatically when a link is clicked from the server side, you have to send the file back yourself rather and add a couple of custom headers to the output. The way to do this is to use `Response.TransmitFile()` to explicitly send the file from your ASP.NET application and then add the Content Type and Content-Disposition headers.

For example:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=someFIle.xls");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/somewhere/someFIle.xls") );
Response.End();
```

This will cause a Open / Save As dialog box to pop up with the filename of `someFIle.xls` as the default filename preset.

Answer (score 1):

To force downloads, you have to set a couple of http headers. Content-Type and Content-Disposition. The first has to be application/octet-stream, and the second has to look something like this:

Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename="[path to file user wants to download]"